# Using vue-js-modal, how do I access the data passed to the modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

In my vue.js app, I need to show custom data inside a modal. I am using `vue-js-modal` to be able to show a modal from anywhere inside my app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal

I have created a very simple custom modal template to try it out, called `ItemModal.vue`:

```
<template>
    <modal name="item-modal">
        <b>{{item.name}}</b>
    </modal>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'item-modal',
        props: [ 'item' ]
    }
</script>
```

And I am able to successfully call it from inside my `ItemList.vue` component:

```
<template>
    <div id="content">
        <item-modal></item-modal>
        <li v-for="item in items">
            <a v-on:click="showModal( item )">
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import ItemModal from './ItemModal.vue';
    import Items from '@/api/items';

    export default {
        name: 'items',
        asyncComputed: {
            items: {
                async get() {
                    const items = await Items.getAll();
                    return items.data;
                },
                default: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showModal( item ) {
                this.$modal.show('item-modal', { item: item } );
            }
        },
        components: {
            ItemModal
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, the modal comes up empty.

What am I missing in `ItemModal.vue` to be able to use the data that I'm passing to it within the `showModal` function?

Comment: Suggest you read up on slots. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Answer (score 11):

You should register the plugin in the main.js file of your project, in this way:

```
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
Vue.use(VModal)
```

Then you would be able to call the show function in any place of your project:

```
this.$modal.show('the-name-you-asigned-in-your-modal');
```

If you need to pass params to the modal you can easy receive them in the beforeOpen event handler:

```
//In the template    
<modal name="hello-world" @before-open="beforeOpen"/>


methods: {
  beforeOpen (event) {
    console.log(event.params.foo);
  }
}
```

I know you are pretty close to make it work, so I provide you with a working example so you can take it as reference:

1- Include plugin in your main.js file.

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VModal)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

2- Create a component that contains the modal (Let's call it **Modal.vue**)

```
<template>
  <modal name="hello-world" @before-open="beforeOpen">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>{{ itemToShow }}</p>
    </div>
  </modal>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    data: function () {
      return {
          item: ''
      }
    },

    computed: {
      itemToShow: function () {
        return this.item
      }
    },

    methods: {
      beforeOpen (event) {
        this.item = event.params.item;
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>
```

3- Show the modal component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <Modal />
    <button @click="onClick">
      CLICK HERE!
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Modal from './components/Modal'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      Modal: Modal
    },
    methods: {
      onClick() {
        this.$modal.show('hello-world', {item: 'Hello world'});
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  #app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
```